# How to get data from a mat-list field into an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get data from a `mat-list` field to an `input` field. I tried it with `getElementById` but it's not working. Is there any solution to do it?

here's my code:

```
<div class="material-input">
      <mat-form-field class="form-group" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
        <input matInput id="firstName" onchange="getDataFromList(this.value)" readonly formControlName="firstName">
        <mat-list id="listFirstName" *ngFor="let username of mockLdap | async">
          {{username?.firstName}}
        </mat-list>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
 getDataFromList(val) {
    (document.getElementById('listFirstName') as HTMLInputElement).value = val;
  }
```

Comment: To start off, input element has readonly attribute. Secondly, I would suggest to set input value through Angular's form instead of accessing the HTML element. Maybe if you remove readonly attribute might work? Unfortunately I can't test it right now.

Comment: do you want to use a mat-list-option? or a mat-select? or a list on mat-checkbox? For me has no sense use mat-list for a input :(

Comment: @Eliseo I search a user and get its properties e.g firstName but i can't get it inside ```input``` field and it only works with ```mat-list``` i don't want to use it either but if I leave it out my code crashes